# Python : replacing a space after numbers keeping space after letters

Tags: python, regex

As part of preprocessing my data. I want to be able to replace space followed by a number, keeping the space followed by a character.
For example:

```
Input String: '8.1.7 Sep 2000 Dec 2004 Dec 2006 Indefinite'

Expected output: '8.1.7,Sep 2000,Dec 2004,Dec 2006,Indefinite'
```

I am using the regular expression based replace function in python:

```
re.sub("\s+", ",", release)
```

but this is not fetching the desired result, simply because this meant to replace all spaces, not sure how to keep the one followed by characters i.e. `[a-z]`.

Or maybe I need to rethink on approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a `(?<=\d)` to require a digit before the whitespace:

```
release = re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\s+", ",", release)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRHzXd/1/)

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a digit to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars.

Answer (score 4):

You can  try with backreferences:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d)\s+", r"\1,", '8.1.7 Sep 2000 Dec 2004 Dec 2006 Indefinite')
'8.1.7,Sep 2000,Dec 2004,Dec 2006,Indefinite'
```

So the code is:

```
release = re.sub(r"(\d)\s+", "\1,", release)
```

Explaination:

- `(\d)` match a digit and put it in a first matching group
- `\s+` match whitespaces
- in substitution: `\1` references to the digit you found and puts it back (without spaces)

Comment: this is getting me '8.1.,Sep 200,Dec 200,Dec 200,Indefinite' as result. eating last digit

Comment: well, I hate to say that, but it works for me ;-) Please check [demo](https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingMotionlessBundledsoftware)

Comment: Seems like you are right, something wrong with my IDE,