# Replace a character just before a pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to convert my space delimited file to a CSV. This essentially has a text followed by 3 dates.

I have figured out regular expression based replacement. Although this is working perfectly with REPEL [Regex evaluator](https://regex101.com/r/eRHzXd/4). It is failing in my code

This is what I am doing in my python code

```
re.sub(r"\s(\D{3}\s+\d{4})", ",\1", row)

Input: 'webProbe 3.6.4 64bit  Jan 2008 Dec 2009 Jan 2012 Dec 2010'
Output: 'webProbe 3.6.4 64bit ,,,,'
```

Side-note: I am on pycharm (just in case this is an environment issue) and this question is coming from [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49027196/1069073) which I asked earlier

Comment: Strings are immutable... You need to reassign row

Comment: Please reveal the mystery behind the comment. FYI, I am receiving this on a variable and then using it.

Comment: You forgot to raw-ify the replacement string: `r",\1"`.

Comment: You need to either escape the backslash (`',\\1'`) or use a raw string literal (`r',\1'`).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the full output that contains commas?

Comment: @gilbdud and @ mkrieger1 yes thanks for pointing that one out. it worked

Comment: One of you should post it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @LouisSugy Well, considering he knew about the existence of raw strings (since the pattern was raw) for dealing with backspaces, I considered this question more of the "off topic because typo" type. The topic of raw strings is already well covered here, and I don't see this being a likely landing spot for others searching for similar issues.

Comment: Ok, voted "off topic because typo" then

Comment: @glibdud and Louis sugy. Honestly, I knew nothing about the existence of raw strings. I did figure-out only after you correcting me. I am sure adding an answer will help someone in future.